# How can I switch JPanels remotely?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

The concept I'm trying to work into my program is basically:

-Main Window: a main class that holds the main frame of the program, i.e.:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    ...
}
```

-Other classes: classes that extend JPanel so that they can be easily added to the MainWindow as one object or entity, i.e:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {
    ...
}
```

This way, I can say, for the main window:

```
public MainWindow() {
...
SomePanel sp = new SomePanel();
add(sp);
...
}
```

When some ActionEvent is triggered, I can say, in the MainWindow class:

```
// remove the current panel
getContentPane().remove(sp);
// insert the new panel
getContentPane().add(someOtherPanel);
validate();
repaint();
```

The concept, I suppose, is like CardLayout, except I haven't gotten around to learning CardLayout yet and I felt like trying this concept instead. I'll probably learn CardLayout at some point though, depending on what's easier.

But my main question is, how can I switch between JPanels remotely like that, based on the trigger of an ActionEvent, if everything is in different classes? I thought that there must be some shared component between the classes, but this doesn't seem to be working. Am I on the right track?

The code I'm trying for remove() and add() doesn't seem to be working, as nothing changes when I trigger an ActionEvent for a component (the listener is added and everything). I'm also including validate() and repaint() but still nothing happens.

I'm not a beginner anymore but not incredibly experienced either, so bear with me if there's something obvious I'm missing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7):

You are most definitely on the right track, and almost have it. Notice how you use `add(sp);` in your constructor, but use `getContentPane().remove(sp);` and `getContentPane().add(someOtherPanel);` in the bottom example. There is most definitely a `remove(Component c)` method for `JPanel`'s, so be using that.

Additionally, everything will be easier if you manipulate your components in one spot. I like to do it right in a main method, or in a main sort of class. For example:

```
public class Start implements ActionListener {
    Window theWindow = new Window();
    CustomPanel mainMenu = new CustomPanel();
    CustomPanel optionsMenu = new CustomPanel();
    Button myButton = new Button();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        theWindow.add(mainMenu);
        mainMenu.add(myButton);
        myButton.addActionListener(this);

        theWindow.setVisible(true);
        theWindow.repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(Event e) {
        theWindow.remove(mainMenu);
        theWindow.add(optionsMenu);
        theWindow.repaint();
    }
```

Notice how easy it was to do all this without even having to get into specifics with the custom classes. I suggest structuring your programs and gui's like this.

Also as MadProgrammer states below, you might be able to use `theWindow.revalidate()` instead of `repaint()`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method, I always use `repaint`. Thank you, I have edited my response.

Comment: not (re)validate() must be there, doesn't matter that works for BorderLayout with success, this is command, notifiers for LayoutManager, repaint isn't required for part of standard JComponents

Answer (score 5):

You could devise a model that controls what is display by different actions.  This model would then be shared so that the underlying actions had access to it and it didn't need to expose components unnecessarily.  But that would depend on your requirements...

So, for example.  You could establish a model that allowed you to associate the a component with a named action (for example).  When some action occurs in your application, you would tell the model to `setCurrentAction` and pass it the name of the action to be made available.

You could, further, use something like a `ChangeListener` which would notify the interested party, that the current view has changed and that it should up accordingly.

This way you decouple the model from the UI

**Updated with an example**

This is a proof of concept.  The main point is to demonstrate a means by which you can decouple of model from the UI, so the model doesn't care whose controlling the output, only that it can tell someone...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class PageFlipper {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PageFlipper();
  }

  public PageFlipper() {
    startUI();
  }

  public void startUI() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MainView());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class MainView extends JPanel {

    private DefaultViewModel model;

    public MainView() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      model = new DefaultViewModel();
      model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Current view = " + model.getCurrentViewName());
          removeAll();
          add(model.getCurrentView());
          revalidate();
          repaint();
        }
      });
      model.addView("Menu", new ActionPane("Menu", "Settings", model));
      model.addView("Settings", new ActionPane("Settings", "Menu", model));
      model.setCurrentView("Menu");
    }

  }

  public class ActionPane extends JPanel {

    private final String nextView;
    private final ViewModel model;

    public ActionPane(String name, String nextView, ViewModel model) {
      this.nextView = nextView;
      this.model = model;
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
      label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      add(label);

      JButton btn = new JButton("Next");
      btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          ActionPane.this.model.setCurrentView(ActionPane.this.nextView);
        }
      });
      add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

  }

  public interface ViewModel {

    public void setCurrentView(String name);
    public Component getCurrentView();
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);

  }

  public class DefaultViewModel implements ViewModel {

    private final Map<String, Component> views;
    private final EventListenerList listenerList;
    private String currentView;

    public DefaultViewModel() {
      views = new HashMap<>(25);
      listenerList = new EventListenerList();
    }

    public void addView(String name, Component comp) {
      views.put(name, comp);
    }

    public void removeView(String name) {
      views.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentView(String name) {
      if (currentView == null ? name != null : !currentView.equals(name)) {
        currentView = name;
        fireStateChanged();
      }
    }

    public String getCurrentViewName() {
      return currentView;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getCurrentView() {
      return currentView == null ? null : views.get(currentView);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
      listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
      listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
      ChangeListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
      if (listeners.length > 0) {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
          listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

You could easily modify it to have more meaningful view/action names (ie use some kind of `Object` instead of `String`) as well as provide more advanced navigation (like `next` and `previous` for example)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

~add both of the jpanels once

~whenever there's an event, switch the visibilities of the panels...

example:

```
//global variables
int i = 0;
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
JPanel p = new JPanel();
```

when there's an event call this method: `switchPanels()` , but you can name it how you want...:D

```
public void switchPanels() {
    i++;
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        p.setVisible(true);
        p2.setVisible(false);
    }else{
        p.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```